# How to use scope variables in attributes with string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. I have a issue scope variable not working in script tag. I had try ng-src but still not working.
**script_path** variable not working with script.js if I add only {{script_path}} working fine but if I add {{script_path}}/script.js this is not working.

**My example code**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head ng-controller='HeadCn'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script ng-src="{{script_path}}/script.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="container">
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller("HeadCn", function($scope) {
            $scope.script_path = "js/";
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

please give me solution how to use scope variable anywhere in controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a / in your script_path and also you are adding one more when using ng-SRC so ur path will have 2 slashes which is not a valid path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimbrooism is right, you are getting this error because security concerns are not being handled.

Please read carefully at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

You may need to use other filter as described on that page or you can completely disable sce at config level, which not recommended

Answer (score 0):

use `$sce` resolve the problem, create a filter for solve this problem

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('trustUrl', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    };
  });

<script ng-src="{{script_path}}/script.js | trustUrl "></script>
```

Comment: still not working after added single quotes but thanks for reply. AngularJS v1.5.5

Comment: no error message in console. html display {{script_path}} not "/js"

Comment: sorry console error message.Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: '{{script_path}}/script.js'
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce

Comment: but I want to use scrpt.js in html not in js. I want only path in js

Comment: pls check it now @SamPooran

Comment: still not working console error : Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=%7B%7Bscript_path%7D%7D%2Fscript.js%20%7C%20trustUrl
O/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:6:412